# change select to input in cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change a select list to a text input (an example is amazon cart) based on a value of 10. What I have works for 1 row but I want to add multiple rows. I need some help changing the jquery to only change 1 row at a time.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dropdown-change').on('change', function() {
    var dropdownValue = $(this).val();

    if (dropdownValue == 10) {
      $('.dropdown-control').hide();
      $('.input-control').show();
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-control').show();
      $('.input-control').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.input-control {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row dropdown-row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col sm-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="quantity">Qty</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
    <div class="dropdown-control">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-pad-left">
        <select name="quantity" class="form-control dropdown-change">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10+</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-control">
      <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-left">
        <input type="text" value="10" size="10" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-left">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `only change one row at a time`, please explain what the `rows` are

Comment: Sorry - I need to duplicate the HTML above several times starting with "dropdown-row" but only have the input field show for that specific select list. The way it is now if I duplicate the HTML all input fields show

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing my HTML around and using $(this).closest() and $(this).next()